# $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , Suppose $d =\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f'(x)> 0$. Prove that $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose $d = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f'(x)> 0$. Prove that $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Attempt:

My idea is to prove that $f(x)$ takes both positive and negative values and then to use intermediate theorem to prove the existence of $a$.

On the contrary lets assume that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , since $d>0$ it is a strictly increasing function hence $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) \to 0 \hspace{2cm} (1)$$.

It is given that the function is continuously differentiable

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x) = 0 \hspace{2cm}(2)$$
In the above equation, due to (1) the numerator is bounded and the denominator tends to $\infty$, which contradicts with the assumption that $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f'(x)> 0$.$\hspace{2cm} (3)$

Similar argument can be given to prove that the function cannot take negative values alone.

Hence from IMVT, we can conclude that for such a function there exists an $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a) = 0$.

Specifically my doubt is weather I can draw conclusions (2) and (3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By MVT, for any $b<a$ there exists exists a $b<\xi<a,$ such that
$$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(\xi).$$
So,
$$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\geq d>0.$$
Since $a-b$ is positive,
$$f(a)-f(b)\geq (a-b)d.$$

Now assume $f(a)>0$, then by letting $b$ become small enough, the RHS becomes very large, so, $f(b)$ must cross to negative value for this to b possible. So, we get change of sign in $f$, thus w must have a zero of it.

If $f(b)<0$, then let $a$ grow large and positive, then $f(a)$ must become positive to keep up with the RHS.

So, pick a random point, say, $0$, then either $f(0)=0$, which is what we wanted! Or it is either positive or negative. If positive choosing $a=0$ proves that $f$ has a root. If negative, choose $b=0$ and prove that $f$ has a zero.

**Note:** To come up with this, think about it geometrically, it tells you that you have at least d(b-a) vertical difference in values of $f$ at a and b. By making this difference large enough, we see that somewhere we have them on opposite sides of $x$-axis.

Comment: I got your proof, thanks. My proof is motivated by asymptotic nature of the function near the x axis...could you verify my proof and see weather conclusion (2) and (3) are valid?

Comment: How could 2 be true if inf of f' is positive? Also why x approaching negative infinty there?

Comment: Ok ok! Yes, it is true under those assumptions that f' has to approach zero. That is if monotone f has x axis as its horizontal asymptote then its derivative must approach zeron. But this needs a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $f(0) > 0$. Put $\inf_\mathbb{R}f' = d>0$. Define the function $y(x) = f(0) + dx$. Graphically, $y$ is the line passing through $f(0)$ with $f$'s "minimum slope", so intuitively, $f$ should have a zero before $y$ does.

Put $a = d/f(0)>0$ and note that $y(-a) = 0$. We will show that $f$ has a zero in the interval $I=[-a,0]$.

Suppose that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in I$. Then, since $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$, $|f(-a) - f(0)| < f(0)$. Simultaneously, by the mean value theorem, $|f(-a)-f(0)| = f'(c)a$ for some $c$ between $-a$ and $0$. However, $f'(c) \ge d$, so that $|f(-a)-f(0)| \ge da = f(0)$.

Thus, we have that the two inequalities $|f(-a) - f(0)| < f(0)$ and $|f(-a) - f(0)| \ge f(0)$ hold at once, which is a contradiction. Thus, our assumption that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in I$ must have been faulty, and there exists a zero of $f$ in $I$, as desired.

Comment: @AOeriz thanks for the proof. could you comment on my proof specifically regarding the conclusions i have made in (2) and (3).

Comment: @spaceman_spiff What is your definition of $h$? I can't really tell what you're saying around your (2).

Comment: thanks i got what was wrong with the proof..