# If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function and $\inf F'(x)= t>0$ then prove that $F(x)=0$ for some real $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose $\delta = \inf_{ x\in\mathbb{R}}f'(x) > 0.$ Prove that $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168042/321264

Answer (score 0):

For $y<0$ we have $$f(0)-f(y)=\int_y^0f'(t)dt\geq \int_y^0\delta dt=(0-y)\delta=|y|\delta.$$  If $y<0$ and  $|y|\delta> |f(0)|$ then $f(0)-f(y)\geq |y|\delta\implies f(y)<0.$

For $z>0$ we have $$f(z)-f(0)=\int_0^zf'(t)dt\geq \int_0^z\delta dt=z\delta.$$ If $z>0$ and $z\delta>|f(0)|$ then $f(z)-f(0)\geq z\delta\implies f(z)>0.$

Since $\exists y<0\;(f(y)<0)$ and $\exists z>0\;(f(z)>0)$ and $f$ is continuous,there exists $a\in (y,z)$ with $f(a)=0.$

By a minor modification to this we can show that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Can you please tell me that How do you know that $|y|$$\delta > |f(0)|$ and same for the z?

Comment: @LAMDA .We don't. Suppose $f(0)\ne 0.$ What we have is $y\in (-|f(0)|\delta^{-1},0)\implies f(y)<0.$

Answer (score 0):

From the mean value theorem for $x>y$ we get
$$\frac{f(x) -f(y)}{x-y}   = f'(\xi) \geq t$$
Take $$\liminf _{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{f(x) -f(y)}{x-y}=\liminf _{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{ f(y)}{y} \geq t>0$$
Which implies that $\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} f(y) = -\infty$, similary taking $x\rightarrow \infty$ we see that $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) =\infty$ so we conclude.